# Parallax effect is laggy an jumps

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

Ok. Im trying to make a parallax website that works on every browser. I have achieved the effect on all browsers but it is laggy and jumpy in some browsers. Is there any way to make it smooth?

Here is my code

```js
function Draw(){
    requestAnimationFrame(Draw);
    scrollEvent();
}

Draw();

function scrollEvent(){
    var height = $(window).height();

    if($(document).scrollTop() <= height){
        $('#home').css('transform', 'translate3d(0, ' + ($(document).scrollTop() + 'px, 0)'));
        $('#about').css('transform', 'translate3d(0, ' + ($(document).scrollTop() - height + 'px, 0)'));
    }else if($(document).scrollTop() <= 2*height){
        $('#about').css('transform', 'translate3d(0, ' + ($(document).scrollTop() -height +  'px, 0)'));
        $('#gallery').css('transform', 'translate3d(0, ' + ($(document).scrollTop() - 2*height + 'px, 0)'));
    }else if($(document).scrollTop() <= 3*height){
        $('#gallery').css('transform', 'translate3d(0, ' + ($(document).scrollTop() -2*height + 'px, 0)'));
        $('#blog').css('transform', 'translate3d(0, ' + ($(document).scrollTop() - 3*height + 'px, 0)'));
    }else if($(document).scrollTop() <= 4*height){
        $('#blog').css('transform', 'translate3d(0, ' + ($(document).scrollTop() -3*height+ 'px, 0)'));
        $('#contact').css('transform', 'translate3d(0, ' + ($(document).scrollTop() - 4*height + 'px, 0)'));
    }
}
```

```css
/*...............................fonts..................................*/
@font-face {
    font-family: 'aka-acid-typogroteskregular';
    src: url('../fonts/actypogrotesk-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/actypogrotesk-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/actypogrotesk-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../fonts/actypogrotesk-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/actypogrotesk-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/actypogrotesk-webfont.svg#aka-acid-typogroteskregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

.font{
 font-family: 'aka-acid-typogroteskregular';
}

/*...............................colors..................................*/
.black{
 color:#000000;
}

.white{
 color:#ffffff;
}

/*...............................text-centering..................................*/
.text-center{
 text-align:center;
}

.text-right{
 text-align:right;
}

/*...............................navigation..................................*/
nav{
 padding-right:100px;
}

nav ul{
 list-style:none;
}

nav ul li{
 padding:30px 20px 20px 20px;
 cursor:pointer;
}

nav ul li:hover{
 color:#DCDCDC;
}

*{
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
   -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
   -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
   backface-visibility: hidden;
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 letter-spacing:2px;
}

.inline{
 display:inline-block;
 *display:inline;
 zoom:1;
}

html, body
{
    width:100%;
 height:100%;
}

.cont{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
}


.rlt-container{
 position:absolute;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
    display:block;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position:center top;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
   -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
   -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
   backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.first{
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
   -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
   -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
   transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.others{
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100, 0);
   -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 100, 0);
   -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 100, 0);
   transform: translate3d(0, 100, 0);
}

.overlay123{
 position:absolute;
 width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:999;
 background-image: url('../media/backgrounds/dark_overlay.png');
}

.title-cont{
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 top:50%;
 margin-top:-49.5px;
}

.title{
 font-size:82px;
 font-weight: 200;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <?php include 'incl/base_url.php';?>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/global.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
   <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/plugins/ScrollToPlugin.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <!--Home-->
  <div class="cont">
   <div class="overlay123">
    <header>
     <?php include 'incl/nav.php';?>
    </header>
    <div class="title-cont text-center">
     <h2 class="title font white">Liokoki</h2>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div id="home" class="rlt-container first" style="background-image: url('media/backgrounds/MG_0069.jpg');">

   </div>
  </div>
  <!--About-->
  <div class="cont">
   <div class="overlay123">
    <div class="title-cont text-center">
     <h2 class="title font white">About</h2>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div id="about" class="rlt-container others" style="background-image: url('media/backgrounds/MG_0129.jpg');">

   </div>
  </div>
  <!--Gallery-->
  <div class="cont">
   <div class="overlay123">
    <div class="title-cont text-center">
     <h2 class="title font white">Gallery</h2>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div id="gallery" class="rlt-container others" style="background-image: url('media/backgrounds/MG_0107.jpg');">

   </div>

  </div>
  <!--blog-->
  <div class="cont">
   <div class="overlay123">
    <div class="title-cont text-center">
     <h2 class="title font white">Blog</h2>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div id="blog" class="rlt-container others" style="background-image: url('media/backgrounds/MG_0142.jpg');">

   </div>
  </div>
  <!--Contact-->
  <div class="cont">
   <div class="overlay123">
    <div class="title-cont text-center">
     <h2 class="title font white">Contact</h2>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div id="contact" class="rlt-container others" style="background-image: url('media/backgrounds/DJI_0011.jpg');">

   </div>
  </div>
  <script src="js/effects.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `transition: transform 200ms ease;` to the elements that are being transformed. This should add a transition th e the transforms that you're applying in your js.